# Library is not copied to Tomcat directory when deploying

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am developing a JSP application to test calling a servlet with AJAX that returns a JSON object. I am using Eclipse as IDE. As library for processing JSON I am using Gson. To make that library available in my project I created a `lib` folder inside my source directory and copied the Gson library into it. After reloading the project in Eclipse I included it in my build path. I can use that library in my classes with no problem. 
I configured the JSP application to be deployed to my local Tomcat installation. When running the application everything gets deployed to `.../tomcat/8.0.26/libexec/wtpwebapps/AjaxJson` so that part is working. As I understood it the directory `WEB-INF` contains all the classes and libraries. The `classes` directory contains all the classes I defined, but the `lib` directory is empty. Thats the reason why everytime a servlet is requested that uses the Gson library I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. What do I have to do to get Eclipse to copy libraries into the `lib` directory when deploying the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the mappings in web deployment assembly in project properties. If you use maven, there is no need to copy dependencies manually.

Comment: You mean Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export? I checked gson-2.3.1.jar which resides in the `lib` folder of my source directory. But it does not change anything. It still does not get copied to the application directory in `wtbwebapps` of my local Tomcat installation folder.

Comment: Properties > Deployment Assembly

Comment: I overlooked that tab. That is the solution though. From there I could set that the folder `/lib` of my project should be deployed to `WEB-INF/lib`. Now the library is found. I wonder why this is not set up automatically that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I used Eclipse for building WARs, but I *think* that marking the library as exported in the project Build Properties dialog will do the trick. If not, please do downvote.

Comment: It does not get deployed as WAR archive into the Tomcat directory. When debugging Eclipse just compiles and copies everything into the `wtbwebapps` directory of my local Tomcat installation, but does not include the libraries I added to my project.